# What is the name of this Lego Blacktron anime/cartoon?

Tags: sets, history

Once upon a time, in a distant past there was a Lego Blacktron series:

[image]

The Lego Blacktron series has a logo/symbol, it's a yellow triangle with small black triangle inside.

Now my question is: about 15/20/25 years ago there was a cartoon or anime series in which one of the faction (bad one I think) wears the same symbol as Blacktron series units, do you know the name of that cartoon?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Maybe this question would better fit the [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) or [Movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/)Stack Exchange, as it's more about the tv-series you're looking for than about LEGO, which just reminds you of that symbol.*

### *Zelda*

It absolutely looks like [the Triforce](https://www.google.com/search?q=triforce) of the [video game series *Zelda*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda). There also was a [*Zelda* cartoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda_%28TV_series%29) in the late 1980s / early 1990s. To this point, it seems to fit to your memory — but sadly there's no connection to spaceships, so I assume you where thinking of something else.

### *Starcom*

I found something else: *[Starcom: The U.S. Space Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starcom:_The_U.S._Space_Force)*. It's an animated series from the 1980s, which totally looks like what you're searching:

[image: Dark’s legions of robotic minions]